# HTML5 TAG ADDRESS mailto with links

Tags: html

I want include one e-mail link on my website.
And i want ask if i use a href mailto i need use address tag? And i yet want include twitter and facebbok profile link there. I need address tag to be valid?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You do not need to have `<address>` to make a valid document, and if you have other links in there besides email, it is not invalid or even necessarily wrong.  It's only really "wrong" if you're using `<address>` to markup any old address information, regardless of context.

The `<address>` tag is used to indicate contact information for the owner or maintainer of the document/site. For example, if you are using it to indicate the owner of the document/site you might use:

```
This site is maintained by: 
<address>
   <a href="mailto:you@youraddress.com">Miki</a>
</address>
```

If you want to add other information related to contacting the person in the `<address>` area, you can:

```
This site is maintained by: 
<address>
   Miki (<a href="mailto:you@youraddress.com">email</a>, <a href="http://twitter.com/someone">twitter</a>, etc)
</address>
```

Here's some [straightforward info](http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/) about the `<address>` element.